# Bash : Piping to eog

Tags: bash

I'm trying to pipe a filename via bash code to eog.

Here's my code : `ls | grep "sample" | head -1` where sample is the name of the required file.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pipe the output to eog.

I've tried storing the output of above code to a variable and then pass that variable to eog unsuccessfully.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `eog`?  A file?  A program?  For my money, write the code as a shell script and make it executable; failing that, make it a function.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to call eog with the filename as an argument or do you want to write the filename to eog's stdin? I don't think the latter would accomplish anything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: [Eye of GNOME](http://projects.gnome.org/eog/), an image viewer.

Comment: @sepp2k Yeah, I want to call eog with the filename as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ls | grep "sample" | head -1 | xargs eog
```

Answer (score 3):

One can say, than parsing output from the `ls` sometimes can go wrong (e.g. spaces, or newlines in the filename), so you can try the next:

```
 find . -iname '*sample*' -exec eog '{}' \; -quit
```

or limit to current dir

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*sample*' -exec eog '{}' \; -quit
```

the above will find any file what contains "sample" (case insensitive - use `-name` for case sensitive) and will run `eog` on it - and will quit after the 1st match, so will open the first file only.

Answer (score 1):

eog ("The eye of gnome") doesn't let you pipe files into it. You have to supply the filename as a command line parameter.

If there were only one matching filename, you could just type:

```
eog *sample*
```

But that would have the effect of showing all files in the current directory whose names include the word `sample`. It's not clear to me why you would expect the alphabetically first such file to be the one to display, but you could do so with:

```
eog $(ls *sample* | head -n1)
```

You might prefer to find a more specific pattern, though.